# How to register custom class for using in controller method?

Tags: laravel

There is a static class with a method which returns data by type:

```
class FactoryProfileModel {
    static function get($type) {
        if ($type === Type.Doctor) return DoctorModel::where("user_id", 1);
        if ($type === Type.Patient) return PatientModel::where("user_id", 1);
     } 
}
```

How and where to register such a class `FactoryProfileModel` to use it in the controller method where `$request->type` arrives.

May be better use this as helper function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a folder inside your APP Folder and name a file like your class name. After you created it you can USE is it in your Controller by importing it with "use App\Classes\FPDF".
After you can call it easy with $classInstance = new Class();